# Einstein warped product manifold Ricci flat

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, general-relativity

Let $(M,g)=(N,\ddot{g})\times f(B,\bar{g})$ be an Einstein warped-product manifold Ricci flat (i.e. $Ric=\lambda g$ with $\lambda=0$) where $f:N \rightarrow (0, \infty)$ (positive scalar function) and with $g= \ddot{g}+f^2 \bar{g}$.

If $(B, \bar{g})$ is Ricci flat, being $(M, g)$ Ricci flat, this means that $(N, \ddot {g})$ must be only Ricci flat or not?

Comment: Corollary 7.43 of O'Neill https://books.google.at/books?id=CGk1eRSjFIIC&pg=PA211&lpg=PA211&dq=tensorfield++zero+at+a+point&source=bl&ots=eRwNYZFJES&sig=SBiANvN_Q0Ge1t9kW6N01geZH_c&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNpq7s6_rbAhXMhSwKHY-gDbwQ6AEIPzAH#v=onepage&q=tensorfield%20%20zero%20at%20a%20point&f=false shows how the Ricci curvature of the warped product looks like. Note that he uses $f$ instead of $f^2$ as warping factor.

Comment: @Clemens Sämann  - Thank you for the reply, then for what I see in the Corollary 7.43, even if the Einstein warped product manifold and Fiber manifold are both Ricci flat, not necessarily the Base manifold must be Ricci flat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\bar M=M_1\times_f M_2$ be a warped product manifold, $X_1, Y_1$ be two lifts of two vector fields on $M_1$ to slides $M_1\times p_2$ and $X_2, Y_2$ be two lifts of two vector fields on $M_2$ to slides $p_1 \times M_2$. Then
$$\bar Ric(X_1,Y_1)= Ric^1(X_1,Y_1)-\frac{dimM_2}{f}Hess^f(X_1,Y_1)$$
$$\bar Ric(X_2,Y_2)= Ric^1(X_2,Y_2)-f^*g_2(X_2,Y_2)$$
where $f^*=f\Delta f-(dimM_2-1)g_1(grad f, grad f)$, $Ric^i$ is the lift of the Ricci curvatire tensor to $M_i$ and $\bar Ric$ is the Ricci curvature of $\bar M$. Now assume that $\bar M$ and $M_1$ are Ricci flat, then
$$0= -\frac{dimM_2}{f}Hess^f(X_1,Y_1)$$
$$0= Ric^2(X_2,Y_2)-f^*g_2(X_2,Y_2)$$
The first equation implies that $Hess^f$ is zero i.e. the gradient of $f$ is a constant say $c$ and consequently
$$f^*=f\Delta f-(dimM_2-1)g_1(grad f, grad f)=-(dimM_2-1)c^2$$
Thus the second factor is Einstein.
Now assume that $\bar M$ and $M_2$ are Ricci flat, then
$$0= Ric^1(X_1,Y_1)-\frac{dimM_2}{f}Hess^f(X_1,Y_1)$$
$$0= -f^*g_2(X_2,Y_2)$$
Then the first equation yields by tracing 
$$r_1=\frac{dimM_2}{f}\Delta f$$ 
and consequently the second equation implies
$$ f^*=f\Delta f-(dimM_2-1)g_1(grad f, grad f)=0$$
i.e. 
$$r_1f^2=dimM_2(dimM_2-1)g_1(grad f, grad f)$$

Comment: thank you for the reply, but in my question I have $M_2$ and $\bar {M}$ both Ricci flat, not $M_1$

Comment: OK. Noted I will add this case.

Comment: Then the Base manifold not necessarily Ricci flat

Comment: I think yes.....

Answer (score 3):

If you also assume that $(N,\ddot g)$ is complete, then your assumptions imply that $(N,\ddot g)$ is Ricci flat.  I proved this in my article [*The nonexistence of quasi-Einstein metrics*](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2741248).